# OS X: When a notification is closed in one computer why it is still present in another computer?

Tags: macos, data-synchronization, calendar, notifications, apns

Got two computers with the same OS X version, with the same account name and Apple ID, I will call these two equipments A and B.

When a notification pops-out from Calendar app in A the same goes for B, when closed the notification in A, B still shows the notification. The same is true if closed first in B then A keeps showing the notification.

This means that while using A and closing these notifications if you go back to B the same notifications need to be closed again.

Is there a way to make OS X aware that some notifications in B were already viewed and closed in A (sync)?

Comment: I believe this is the intended functionality, since there is no way to really guarantee that you were the person who closed the notification. AFAIK there is nothing (except possibly a 3rd-party app) that could do this.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to remove notifications, at the time of writing, is to take action on the notification. For example, closing a message notification doesn't close it anywhere else, but tapping the message notification and opening Messages does.

You can provide feedback to Apple here:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html

Comment: Tapping or clicking on a e.g. Calendar notification does not close it, the calendar app will be open but the notification will stay until the "close" button in the notification is pressed. Still closing a notification in one computer does not close the same notification in another computer which is what I would like to have.